# Is content on SE licensed under CC-BY-SA v3 or v4 now?

Tags: support, creative-commons

The footer on the website says CC-BY-SA 3.0:

[image: Footer linking to CC-BY-SA 3.0]

However the [terms and conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) page link to CC-BY-SA 4.0:

[image: T&C page linking to v4]

So which one is it now officially? V3 or V4?

Comment: Maybe it is licensed under both? Is v4 backward compatible with v3?